# Change multiple properties with single ObjectAnimator?

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I have a pretty complex animation I need to code and I'm using a bunch of ObjectAnimators like the following:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, TRANSLATION_X, value).setDuration(BASE_DURATION * 2);
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, TRANSLATION_Y, value).setDuration(BASE_DURATION * 2);
```

Is it possible to group the X and Y translations into the same ObjectAnimator rather than creating a bunch of them then adding them all into an AnimatorSet?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of TRANSLATION_X / TRANSLATION_Y try your own property, let it be "myProperty" and see what happens

Comment: I can't do that. TRANSLATION_Y is just a constant. It's actually "translationY" which is the property used to translate along the Y axis. I can't create one, at least I don't think I can!

Comment: ok try something like: ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "myProperty", value)

Comment: I'm confused. What is "myProperty" ???

Comment: this is an animated property: when you start that Animator the framework will call this.setMyProperty(float) method several times where you can animate other properties as you want

Comment: Correct. It must be a pre-defined property of the view. How would I merge two properties using this proposed method??]

Comment: just cal view.setTranslationX(float)/view.setTranslationY(float)/whatever in setMyProperty method

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but unfortunately this method won't help with what I'm aiming to do.

Comment: yes it will help, just create a public void setMyProperty(float param) and call whatever you want inside it

Comment: That is not what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: you want to change view's x and y position, right? so call view.setTranslationX(x); view.setTransletionY(y) inside setMyProperty()

Comment: No. I want to group two properties into one ObjectAnimator.

Comment: thats exactly what i'm saying! in your Activity just try: ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "myProperty", start, end)

Comment: You're a very stubborn guy, I have to say. Thanks for your help.

Comment: stubborn? i made it several times, so i know what i'm saying... but if you insist, well, i cannot force you...

Comment: Clearly you're trying to force me lol

Comment: What @pskink suggests is the only way to go about this since ObjectAnimator can not handle more than one property. However, I don't really see the problem with not grouping them. If you don't need to add them to the AnimatorSet, see my answer below.

Comment: That's all I really wanted to know. Whether or not ObjectAnimator can handle more than one property at a time. I guess it can't! Thanks :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(TRANSLATION_X, value);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(TRANSLATION_Y, value);
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, pvhX, pvhY);
animator.setDuration(BASE_DURATION * 2);
animator.start();
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views
 One ObjectAnimator

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider, you should've accepted the answer ;)

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider, What? It does exactly what you were asking for. It groups several of `ObjectAnimators` into a single one, that lets you animate multiple `Properties`.

Comment: @blipinsk Fair enough :) Cheers!

Answer (score 24):

I think you should be using an **AnimationSet**.
It practically does what you want and is the nice way of doing it because when I think of **PropertyValuesHolder** I don't think of **Keyframes**.

So yeah:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, TRANSLATION_X, value);
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, TRANSLATION_Y, value);

AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimator1, objectAnimator2);
animatorSet.setDuration(BASE_DURATION * 2);

animatorSet.start();
```

You can add as many *ObjectAnimators* as you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you are animating a view (like your example suggests), you could use a ViewPropertyAnimator:

```
view.animate().translationX(value_x).translationY(value_y).setDuration(duration).start();
```

Comment: Would I be able to add a ViewPropertyAnimator into a set? Something similar to an AnimatorSet?

Comment: I thought you were trying to avoid creating a AnimatorSet. No you wouldn't be able to add it to an AnimatorSet. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not entirely, no. So my AnimatorSet is used to move a bunch of different objects around, but I'd like to group each object's animations (X/Y translations, scales, etc) into a single object

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach I've used to add multiple properties to an object's animation is to use a mix of code and XML to define the animation. This is based on this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml)

For example, in XML I can setup AnimatorSets and ObjectAnimators for a single object with static values, and define a sequential sequence of changes (res/animator/moveout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:valueTo="0.8"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:valueTo="0.8"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:valueTo="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
    </set>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:valueTo="1.2"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:valueTo="1.2"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
    </set>
</set>
```

Then I can load these AnimatorSets/ObjectAnimators at runtime and modify their values with dynamically generated values:

```
    AnimatorSet firstSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,
            R.animator.moveout);

    AnimatorSet secondSet = firstSet.clone();
    firstSet.setTarget(button);
    secondSet.setTarget(anotherButton);

    // Choreograph the animations
    // Change the duration of all child elements in the set
    firstSet.setDuration(1000);
    secondSet.setDuration(200);

    // Set start delay so second set plays after the first set
    secondSet.setStartDelay(2000);
    AnimatorSet anim = new AnimatorSet();
    anim.playTogether(firstSet,secondSet);
    anim.start();
```

Comment: how can we share the same `interpolator, duration` between multiple ObjectAnimators?

Answer (score 3):

Animating view could be done even easier:

```
v.animate().x(valueX).y(valueY).setDuration(500).start();
```

(In this snippet ViewPropertyAnimator has been used).