# Could not find property setter method 'setScaleX' on 'java.lang.Object'

Tags: android, android-animation

Android Lint gives me such a warning:

> Could not find property setter method 'setScaleX' on
>   'java.lang.Object'

Please look at the screenshot:

[image]

What should I do?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: You can change PropertyValuesHolder by ObjectAnimator. Just like you can found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352352/change-multiple-properties-with-single-objectanimator